# Windows .appx code signing process with Electron

Tags: windows, ionic-framework, electron, code-signing

I have compiled an Ionic app into a Desktop app with Electron and I got an .appx file at the end, but when it comes to signing the app, the process of how to sign and which type of certificate I should use (whether a normal one or an EV one) is not clear to me.

I used `@capacitor-community/electron` to compile my Ionic app to an Electron app, then I used `electron-packager` to get the .exe build, then I used `electron-windows-store` to get the final build which was the .appx file.

How do I continue from here?

Comment: Make sure you have to, appx packages are normally signed by the Store, after you submitted it and it passed verification.  Only sign if you deploy a private package for internal use.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/appxpkg/how-to-sign-a-package-using-signtool